# App for indexing and OCR

Tags: appexchange, app

Salesforce has a rudimentary indexing tool when files are uploaded.  If there is a rendered or created PDF or a word document then all of the text can be indexed and searched.   However, if I upload a scanned documented of a PDF or a TIFF/jpg then I lose that indexing functionality.

I've been looking for OCR solutions.  Most don't seem to index but they do read fields and upsert records.  Is there an OCR document indexing app?

Comment: Go to the app exchange and type in OCR in the search box. Six apps immediately came up for me when I did that just now.

Comment: I did that.  I'm curious about the indexing piece.  Most of these are for upsert.

Comment: perhaps not a great solution but if your users are internal, train them to use adobe acrobat standard or pro editions that do support conversion of a PDF to an OCR'd PDF - then upload. We did this at my last gig